# Firebase - building Audiences based on custom Event Parameters

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Is it possible? I can't add any custom parameter when I'm creating new Audiences at Firebase.

[Custom parameter for click_at_ad event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87PEg.png)

[Missing custom parameter in Audiences for click_at_ad event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9veU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom events but the custom events should be sent first for auto-complete. If the event name is not in the autocomplete list, you can type in the name and hit Enter.